# Getting distances from points to polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance

I'm looking at finding the distance in QGIS between a few things.

Basically, I'll have a points layer, and a polygon layer. Both will have several features in them.

I need to find the distance from each point to each polygon. I can potentially get the centroid and use that (and I think that's what will probably be used), but bonus points for the nearest edge of each polygon to the point in question.

Also, for some reason, v.distance doesn't seem to be appearing in my processing toolbox.

Also tried getting centroids and using the distance matrix, however that's giving me incorrect values.

EDIT - I've done a quick trial (still waiting for the actual data) using the standard distance matrix and measuring to centroids. This works well, but unfortunately the measurements returned are slightly out. This will probably be down to the coordinate system, and I'll have to see what the actual data is like when I get it.

Unfortunately, MMQGIS's hub distance only finds the nearest (and even then, not to the edge of the polygon but to a point within, which doesn't appear to be the centroid).

In any case, the people after this data say that the centroid is okay - they just need to get me the data (which is a tad frustrating, as it is due today).

Comment: Although there are no question marks in your question body you seem to be asking 3-4 questions so I think you should focus on one, so that you can describe precisely what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Would mmqgis plugin for QGis and its hub distance function work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, that only does the nearest shape, and still goes to a point within the shape - not to the edge.